# Prove that $n \geq \sqrt{n-1} + \sqrt{n}$ for $n \geq 4$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, induction, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am trying to prove that $n \geq \sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}$ for $n \geq 4$ (n in naturals of course). I am not sure if there are any specific inequalities that could help me out here. I also know that 4 is not exactly the "base" case, I just chose it arbitrarily as I am trying to compare two series. I attempted induction but am not sure if it is the correct way to do it.

Comment: The inequality in the title is different from the one in the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, $\sqrt {n-1}+\sqrt{n} \lt {2\sqrt n}$

$\forall n\in N$

For $n\ge 4,$ $2\sqrt n \le n$

Thus we have proved that $n \gt\sqrt {n-1}+\sqrt{n}$

$\forall n \ge 4$

Answer (score 2):

Using that $4\leq n $, written as $2\leq\sqrt n $, we have $$
\sqrt {n-1}+\sqrt n\leq2\sqrt n\leq (\sqrt n)^2=n.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $a+b\leq\sqrt{2(a^2+b^2)}$, we obtain:
$$\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}\leq\sqrt{2(n+n-1)}=\sqrt{4n-2}\leq\sqrt{4n}\leq n$$